# Convert integer or decimal number to string

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert numbers in text format. It could be integers and decimal numbers.

If convert integer without `regexp_replace` like

`select to_char(999,'FM9999.9') from dual;`

`999.`

Solution for this problem is 
`regexp_replace(to_char(999.9,'FM9999.9'),'[.]$')`

Are there any other way to do it without `regexp_replace` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `trim` or `rtrim` functions:

```
select to_char(999,'FM9999.9') as plain,
  rtrim(to_char(999,'FM9999.9'),'.') as trimmed
from dual;

PLAIN   TRIMMED
------- -------
999.    999
```

[Documentation for the `rtrim` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions160.htm).

You can't do it within the `to_char()` call though, if that is what you were hoping for; there isn't a [format model element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) that makes the decimal separator optional depending on whether there are decimal digits.